# Spring Integration Testing: Could not detect default resource locations

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test

I am running integration tests for my Spring Boot application with Maven's Failsafe plugin. When I create a simple test such as this one:

```
@RunWith (SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(App.class)
public class MyTestIT {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertTrue (true);
    }
}
```

And then run `mvn verify` I see the following log entries just before the Spring application starts (e.g. even before the Spring Boot banner):

```
Running org.....MyTestIT
2016-04-14 13:25:01.166  INFO ???? --- [           main] 
    or.sp.te.co.su.AbstractContextLoader               : 
    Could not detect default resource locations for test class 
    [org....MyTestIT]: no resource found for suffixes
    {-context.xml, Context.groovy}.
2016-04-14 13:25:01.175  INFO ???? --- [           main] 
    or.sp.te.co.su.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper      : 
    Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener]
2016-04-14 13:25:01.185  INFO ???? --- [           main] 
    or.sp.te.co.su.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper      : Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@57c758ac, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener@a9cd3b1, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@13e39c73, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@64cd705f, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@9225652, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@654f0d9c]
```

Followed by the Spring Boot banner. The tests then run through without any error. While these messages are printed with an INFO log level and the tests run fine, I guess everything is fine, **but I still find these messages irritating.** So is there something wrong with my configuration? **Should I worry about these messages?**

Even if there was nothing wrong, I would still like to understand whats happending there and what the messages mean.

My `maven-failsafe-plugin` is just using the default configuration and my `App.java` is just a simple class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`.

**UPDATE 1:**

Here is the configuration of my test plugins:

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <!-- Ignore any tests that are marked by the @IntegrationTest annotation of Spring Boot -->
      <excludedGroups>org.springframework.boot.test.IntegrationTest</excludedGroups>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>

  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>integration-test</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>integration-test</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

I also have a `spring-boot-starter-test` dependency configured and I am using `spring-boot-devtools`. Besides that everything else is not test related.

The project it self is pretty standard, using hibernate and mysql and web-mvc for rest endpoints. I have two configuration classes for spring security on the class pass.

In the `main/resources` folder I have an `application.properties` file and a log4j2.xml. There is no `test/resources` folder, but when I just copy the main/resources folder to `test/resources` the above log messages still appear.

**UPDATE 2:**
I just created a small sample application trying to recreate the issue, and it seems the mentioned log-output starts to appear as soon as I put a `log4j2.xml` file into a resources folder. I tried putting it in `src/main` or `src/test` or both with identical effects.

Comment: Looks weird to me. If that's using the default configuration, you could just as well share a project that reproduces that problem, right?

Comment: Please share some more details like project structure, pom.xml test configuration file. Because when your running integration testing, spring boot should be running before executing the test cases.

Comment: Do you have a resource folder for the tests as well?

Comment: @dambros I currently do not have a resources folder for tests, but I did create one and the problem did not go away by that.

Comment: @StéphaneNicoll @Hareesh I updated the question. And while updating it, I created a small demo project to see if I could reproduce it there and it seems that adding a `log4j2.xml` causes the mentioned log output. Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is the default behaviour when running Spring integration tests.

From the reference documentation

> > **If you omit both the locations and value attributes from the @ContextConfiguration annotation, the TestContext framework will attempt to detect a default XML resource location. Specifically, GenericXmlContextLoader and GenericXmlWebContextLoader detect a default location based on the name of the test class. If your class is named com.example.MyTest, GenericXmlContextLoader loads your application context from "classpath:com/example/MyTest-context.xml".**

So, it's not related whatsoever to Maven, log4j or the positioning/assistance of resource folder.

**Should I worry about these messages?**

Not at all, apparently.

**but I still find these messages irritating**

Don't know if and how to turn off that check (Course you can eliminate it by changing the log level of `AbstractContextLoader` to `WARN`).

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it works exactly as described in the quoted documentation. Good to know this feature. I guess for now I will just ignore these log messages, but next time I need to setup a custom configuration for one of my integration tests this will come in very handy.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `AnnotationConfigContextLoader` in combination with `@Configuration.`

See [here](https://spring.io/blog/2011/06/21/spring-3-1-m2-testing-with-configuration-classes-and-profiles) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

You can annotate you test class with more specific configs for loader and use Java Config

Something like:

```
@ContextConfiguration(loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class, classes = ScalaTestConfig.class)
```

Where ScalaTestConfig class is annotated with:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"***", "***"})
```

Based on abhi's link.